# How to make restful services using an already existing EJB project?

Tags: rest, web-services, ejb

So, the thing is that I have to do some Web Services to use them in a JSF Web App. I also have a desktop application (the executable) and this program already has the EJB with all the layers needed (DAO, controller, etc). So, to specify, my question is: Can I do WebServices (Restful) which consumes this EJB previously made? In other words, reciclying it?

I'm a little lost in this aspect and, even though a searched for an answer didn't find any so specific.

Thanks in advance for any response!  (Also sorry in advance for any grammar errors, English is not my native language =) )

Comment: You can inject EJB services into your JAX-RS resource classes. This is standard. It should be in the Java EE docs in the chapter about JAX-RS

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to reuse already existing code in your jsf app. 
So, to do this you need:

1. Extract ejb from desktop application to external jar;
2. Create enterprise web application (ear) and package jar from first step inside the ear file. Create necessary restful web service;
3. Also you use this jar in you desktop app;
4. Deploy the ear to application server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create http client layer in your JSF application and call REST services in your EJB backend. You will share DTO classes between JSF and EJB applications.